# Dart, why won't my shape show up?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, dart, dart-editor, dartium

I'm trying to make it so at each position my mouse is going to a black circle is generated, but I can't get it to show up, I know I'm receiving input but I have no idea why my stuff isn't showing up? Is there some sort of repaint method that I'm missing? I've tried quite a few things I don't really understand how `requestAnimation` would work here.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

CanvasElement canvas = document.querySelector('#myPaintCanvas');
CanvasRenderingContext2D context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//circle deminsions
var centerX;
var centerY;
var radius = 15;
var PI = 3.14;

void requestRedraw(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scribble());
 }

void scribble(pointX, pointY){
 print("MouseX: " + pointX.toString() + " MouseY: " + pointY.toString());


context.arc(pointX, pointY, radius, 0, 2 * PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fill();
context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
context.stroke();

}

void main(){
 canvas.onMouseDown.listen((onDown){

    StreamSubscription mouseMoveStream = canvas.onMouseMove.listen((onData){
     scribble(onData.client.x, onData.client.y);
    });

//to end my stream when the mouse is up
canvas.onMouseUp.listen((onData) => mouseMoveStream.cancel());
  });

}
```

Comment: I just added this to it and it's giving an error it says that scribble() can't be a void, but what else would you make that type of function?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` takes `RequestAnimationFrameCallback` as its argument that is function from num to void `typedef void RequestAnimationFrameCallback(num highResTime);` and you are trying to pass result  of a `scribble` that is `void` `window.requestAnimationFrame(scribble());` You can wrap it in `(_)=>scribble(x,y)` then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, most likely, have scaling problem due to mismatch between the canvases actual  drawing dimension and it's dimension as a DOM element (`canvas.width = 500;` and `canvas.style.width="500px";`)

Fixed scaling + some additional fixes:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

CanvasElement canvas = document.querySelector('#myPaintCanvas');
CanvasRenderingContext2D context;

//circle deminsions
var centerX;
var centerY;
var radius = 15;
var PI = 3.14;


void scribble(pointX, pointY) {
  print("MouseX: " + pointX.toString() + " MouseY: " + pointY.toString());
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(pointX, pointY, radius, 0, 2 * PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'black';
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
}

void main() {
  canvas.width = 500;
  canvas.style.width="500px";
  canvas.height = 500;
  canvas.style.height="500px";
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.onMouseDown.listen((onDown) {

    StreamSubscription mouseMoveStream = canvas.onMouseMove.listen((onData) {
      var rec = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      scribble(onData.client.x- rec.left, onData.client.y - rec.top);
    });

    //to end my stream when the mouse is up
    document.onMouseUp.listen((onData) => mouseMoveStream.cancel());
  });
}
```

I added  `context.clearRect` to make it clear where the circle is.       `context.beginPath();` and  `context.closePath();`  are needed to prevent bridges between circles. `document.onMouseUp` instead of `canvas.onMouseUp` fixes problem when mouse button is released outside of the canvas.